# Windows 11: Why do DCF and NTFS property pages look different?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, windows-explorer, iphone

I have two "drives" plugged into my computer via USB - one is my iPhone SE (1st gen), and another is my HDD. According to Windows Explorer, the iPhone supposedly uses the DCF file system in its "Internal Storage" and my drive uses NTFS.

I just decided to randomly open the properties of both, just to geek out and see how they're similar. But what I'm more concerned about is why the **property pages themselves** look so different.
[image: iPhone vs HDD Property Pages]

If you have an eagle's eye you'll also notice that the one to the left uses the Tahoma font at 8 points, while the one to the right uses MS Shell Dlg 8 points.

So my question is, if Windows Explorer uses the same code to display properties of different items, then why is the user interface so visually different? (Other than the missing options like "Compress", "Index", etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably not the same code, it's copypasted code to make a *completely* different thing look and feel somewhat the same.

The phone doesn't give you direct access to its memory like a USB stick would. Old Android (and pre-Android) phones used to, nowadays they don't, because doing so would require shutting down the phone's OS and unmounting the storage, and because the phone might use a filesystem that the computer doesn't know. (For example, some Androids use F2FS and iPhones probably use APFS? – you'd need *complex* Windows drivers for each of those.)

Instead your phone is being connected via **MTP**, which means it doesn't get recognized as a disk *at all,* it's actually a lot like accessing an FTP server (except over USB). The host OS doesn't have access to raw memory sectors, so it know nor care about the filesystem that the phone uses; it only exchanges commands like "put file" or "list directory".

So what you're seeing is Explorer acting as an MTP client, talking to the USB device in a very different way than usual disks, and trying its best to *pretend* that this is a disk. (In fact, if I remember correctly, at least in older versions it was a component from *Windows Media Player* that added the MTP support to Explorer as an addon, so it doesn't share code with the existing network share support, either.)

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for. ⭐⭐⭐⭐⭐

Answer (score 0):

I have an iPhone SE (1st) here. This is a fairly old phone. I get the same result as you on my Windows 11 Pro machines (2).  I suspect the difference in display is because the iPhone SE long precedes Windows 11, and the file systems are also very different .

It is (very likely) nothing to be concerned about and not a bug in Windows 11.

Comment: Probably the difference between NTFS and DCF. DCF properties look like a FAT32 disk used while NTFS is your more modern look. Windows is under continuous improvement to get rid of old windows. Looks like Microsoft forgot one. As to the reason they are different only NTFS has file permissions. So it makes sense DCF and FAT32 window wouldn’t be a focus for the art tean